# Why am I getting AccessDenied deploying Gatsby to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby

I'm following [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/) guide to deploy to an S3 bucket using Gatsby.

If I run `aws s3 ls mybucketname.com`,

I get the single file I uploaded: `2019-02-15 15:53:58 477 favicon-16x16.png`

However, if I run `npm run deploy`,

I get this error:

```
> gatsby-plugin-s3 deploy

✖ Failed.
AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Here is the relevant code in my `gatsby-config.js`:

```
plugins: [
{
     resolve: `gatsby-plugin-s3`,
     options: {
         bucketName: 'mybucketname.com'
     },
 },
```

Here is the IAM policy attached to the user I created in AWS:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*Object",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname.com/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Is there something else I can run to determine where this error is coming from?

Comment: how are you singing in from your npm app? it seems to me that you can access via CLI but not from your app because the app does not have the necessary credentials

Comment: I signed in using `aws configure` as mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting `acl: null` in gatsby-plugin-s3 options then run `gatsby build`

```
plugins: [
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-s3`,
  options: {
    bucketName: 'mybucketname.com',
    acl: null
  }
}
```

Comment: you'll need to rebuild gatsby after that.
```gatsby build```

Comment: That also fixed an "access denied" error for an ember-cli-deploy to s3. Nice find.

Comment: The IAM policy that the OP posted is not required for gatsby deploy

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem and it was caused because I hadn't configured yet S3 bucket for website access, which is needed for hosting a website:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Technically it wouldn't be needed by **gatsby-plugin-s3**, since uploading work it's done through AWSCLI using IAM credentials provided; but I guess just listing the bucket before start uploading, or other operation intended to be public, is been executed anonymously instead of using IAM credentials.

Comment: Adding the public read access policy fixed this for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have CloudFront with S3 one of the issues can be rewriting the default index file. To get routes working without `index.html` on the end you have to rewrite requests on the CloudFront. You can do that with lambda functions.

Here is an old doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

New working code is here https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/blob/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps/index.js